# zero prices in sales_flat_order_item for bundled product items

Tags: sales-order, invoice, bundled-product

I have a test bundled product https://www.themertailor.com/dev/test-product-bundle.html

its all working well except the order in the back end shows zero prices for the individual items.

I traced this back to the table sales_flat_order_item which shows all zero prices for the individual items - only the actual bundle shows prices.

This results in zero invoices and errors when paying by credit card.

The magento version is 1.9.2.2

[image: order total ok - items zero price]

Comment: Please show how your bundle product is configured, especially if it's "fixed price" or "dynamic price". Also, do you use any extensions that might be related to bundle products?

Answer (score 0):

sure, its dynamic price with bundled items.
i am using an extension to provide images in the radio buttons for the bundled items.
that is working well and the order is showing all the correct prices, until credit card checkout, when only the shipping is charged. I see in the table sales_flat_order_item shows zero for the bundled items but the full price for the actual bundled product.
[image: prices]
[image: items]